# Volley does not call getParams for my custom request?

Tags: android, get, android-volley

Please, does Volley automatically add my GET params to the URL? For me it's not working so and also when looking into sources, I just cant find any call of the getParams method..
So should I build the URL myself? It's no problem at all, I just thought that when there is such method like getParams, it could do that for me:)

UPDATE: Below is my code..

```
public class BundleRequest extends com.android.volley.Request<Bundle>{

    private String token;
    private OnAuthTokenValidatorResponseListener mListener;
    private final Map<String, String> mParams =  new HashMap<String, String>();;


    public BundleRequest(int method, String url,  Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(method, url, listener);
    }

    public BundleRequest(int method, String url,OnAuthTokenValidatorResponseListener providedListener,  Response.ErrorListener listener, String token) {
        super(method, url, listener);
        this.token = token;
        mListener = providedListener;
        mParams.put(AuthenticatorConfig.TOKEN_VALIDATION_PARAMNAME, token);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mParams;
    }




    @Override
    protected Response<Bundle> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse httpResponse) {
        switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
            case AuthTokenValidator.TOKEN_VALID_RESPONSE_CODE:
                //token is ok
                JSONObject response;
                try {
                        response = new JSONObject(new String(httpResponse.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(httpResponse.headers)));
                        Bundle userDataResponse = new Bundle();
                        userDataResponse.putInt("responseCode", httpResponse.statusCode);
                        userDataResponse.putString("username", response.getString("user_id"));
                        userDataResponse.putString("email", response.getString("user_email"));
                        userDataResponse.putString("expiresIn", response.getString("expires_in"));
                        userDataResponse.putString("scope", response.getJSONArray("scope").getString(0));
                        userDataResponse.putString("token", token);
                    return Response.success(userDataResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(httpResponse));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    return Response.error(new VolleyError("Unsupported encoding"));


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Response.error(new VolleyError("Problem while parsing JSON"));
                }




            case AuthTokenValidator.TOKEN_INVALID_RESPONSE_CODE:
                //token is not valid
                mListener.onValidatorResponse(httpResponse.statusCode);
                try {
                    mListener.onValidatorResponse(parseOnErrorResponse(new String(httpResponse.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(httpResponse.headers))));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            default:
                return Response.error(new VolleyError("Error status code:" + httpResponse.statusCode));

        }
    }

    protected int parseOnErrorResponse(String responseBody) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            String moreInfo = response.getString("more_info");
            if (moreInfo.equals("Token was not recognised")) {
                return AuthTokenValidator.TOKEN_WAS_NOT_RECOGNISED;
            } else if (moreInfo.equals("Token has expired")) {
                return AuthTokenValidator.TOKEN_HAS_EXPIRED;
            } else if (moreInfo.equals("Client doesn't exist anymore")) {
                return AuthTokenValidator.CLIENT_DOES_NOT_EXIST_ANYMORE;
            } else if (moreInfo.equals("Client is locked")) {
                return AuthTokenValidator.CLIENT_IS_LOCKED;
            } else {
                return AuthTokenValidator.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return AuthTokenValidator.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(Bundle response) {
        mListener.onGetUserDataResponse(response);
    }
}
```

Actually the params parameter is now redundant

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getParams()` is not called on the GET method, so it seems you'll have to add it to the URL before you send the request.

Check out the JavaDoc:

> Returns a Map of parameters to be used for a POST or PUT request.
>
> Can throw {@link AuthFailureError} as authentication may be required
>   to provide these values.
>
> Note that you can directly override {@link #getBody()} for custom
>   data.
>
> @throws AuthFailureError in the event of auth failure

Comment: is there any specific reason, why getPrams() is not called on GET ?

Answer (score 1):

As for [Itai Hanski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119033/itai-hanski) answer, this is one example to implement that:

```
 for(String key: params.keySet()) {
   url += "&"+key+"="+params.get(key);
 }
```