# Android: posting to Laravel with Volley doesn't work

Tags: php, android, laravel, android-volley

I'm using google [Volley library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) to handle my application networking.

My backend is an apache server with [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com/). When i'm trying to make a POST request using [JsonObjectRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/43950676303ff68b23a8b469d6a534ccd1e08cfc/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.java) I'm getting an empty `$_POST` array.

I was able to solve it using the method described here: [Volley JsonObjectRequest Post request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working)

but it seems like a solution for simple cases where the object is not very complicated.
Also, i'd like to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and a custom GsonRequest, but it gives the same problem.

Seems odd to me that php and especially Laravel don't know how to deal with JSON requests as this is a REST framework, am I missing something? Is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently the solution is very simple, just needed to dig deeper into documentation :)

http://laravel.com/docs/requests

and specifically this NOTE:

> Some JavaScript libraries such as Backbone may send input to the application as JSON. You may access this data via Input::get like normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. Below is the custom class I created extending class of volley. Parameters is provided as Map

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request {

Map<String, String> params;       
private Response.Listener listener; 

public CustomJsonRequest(int requestMethod, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                      Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = responseListener;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {
    listener.onResponse(response); 

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         return params;
}

@Override
protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

}
```

and you can provide pamas as

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("email", email.getText().toString());
  params.put("password", password.getText().toString());
```

using this you will be able to use GET or POST verbs in your api.

Comment: this is only good for simple cases where the object is flat, but what if you have a complex data structure you want to send?

Comment: I have come across such situation but i think that can be solved by using $_POST['userinfo']['email'].

Answer (score 0):

use this `$_REQUEST` NOT `$_POST` :D