# Way to pass Long parameter in url request using volley

Tags: android, url, post, android-volley, urlencode

Server is **not** accepting **String** parameters when making json object request (by post method) **using volley**, also in custom volley request it is **required to pass a string Hash map in getParams()** method i am having string as well as long values to be pass over there, Also tried by **Uri** class but there is also sting is required in appendQueryParameter(). i have used below links [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465596/send-int-in-hashmap-with-volley)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters) [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android)

```
Volley class
```

public class CustomRequest extends Request {

```
private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String, String> params;

public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                     Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                     Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    this.listener = reponseListener;
    this.params = params;
}

protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
    return params;
}


@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
       /* return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));*/
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    String loginEncoded = new String(Base64.encode(("uictester:?f!T!ziX}.,(").getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + loginEncoded);
    return headers;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listener.onResponse(response);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You first need to convert the long parameter to String using String.valueOf(long value) method and then put this param to the hashmap with its key. as:

params.put("key", String.valueOf(long value));

Comment: yes ! thats what i am doing right now but server does't accept string parameter like in this way .