# Android Volley: null value being received at server for String params sent with POST request

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I am sending `POST` query along with String data from android device using `Volley` library.

The server however, is receiving only `null` values for the params. My code goes like this:

```
        final String param1 = "one";
        final String param2 = "124843";
        final String param3 = "878942";
        final String param4 = "885942";

        String url = getIPAddr()+":"+getPort()+"/com.va.jersey.helloworld/hello";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        showOutput(response);
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        showOutput(error.toString());
                    }
                }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("param1", param1);
                    params.put("param2", param2);
                    params.put("param3", param3);
                    params.put("param3", param4);
                    return params;
                }       //attaching POST params
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I believe there is some error in `StringRequest`, please correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code given below and let me know if you are facing any issue

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        }) {

    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("apiKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        return headers;
    }

};

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

Comment: Error: org.json.JSONException: Value nullnullnullnull of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: could you just get me the url that you are calling?.

Comment: Another post on SO `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135008/unexpected-response-code-500-for-post-method` tells something about replacing `null` in `ObjectRequest` with something...(i don't understand)...

Comment: url is `127.0.0.1:8080/com.va.jersey/helloworld/hello`....i am getting correct response from `HttpRequester` firefox addon

Comment: is it POST or GET?. Also can you tell me the json or string output?

Comment: send me the string output itself

Comment: i'm only appending param2 and param3 and sending it back...for test pupose

Comment: I am expecting the response from server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77796/discussion-between-anant-sophia-and-vinay-jayaram).