# Android Always showing 500 Error

Tags: android, android-volley

I tried following url with POST method.

URL : https://www.rampinteractive.com/api/app/sendmessage/313b4042-3bb3-4e2d-ad42-fd9103ebcdd9/32/-1/-1

Method : POST

parameter : message

But its form data request. Its working fine is PostMan Google Client. Check attached screen shot. But In Android it showing 500 Error. please help me.

[image]
Android Code:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("message", edit_usedid.getText().toString().trim());                callAPI("https://www.rampinteractive.com/api/app/sendmessage/313b4042-3bb3-4e2d-ad42-fd9103ebcdd9/32/40940/1", data, APItype.CUSTOMER_LOGIN);
```

Android Response:

```
    05-02 12:05:57.298 26211-26211/com.syzygy.extreme.sdealscustomer I/System.out: CUSTOMER_LOGIN URL is https://www.rampinteractive.com/api/app/sendmessage/313b4042-3bb3-4e2d-ad42-fd9103ebcdd9/32/40940/1
05-02 12:05:57.299 26211-26211/com.syzygy.extreme.sdealscustomer I/System.out: Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8
05-02 12:05:57.299 26211-26211/com.syzygy.extreme.sdealscustomer I/System.out: message : fsdfdsfsd
05-02 12:05:57.594 26211-26744/com.syzygy.extreme.sdealscustomer E/Volley: [316] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://www.rampinteractive.com/api/app/sendmessage/313b4042-3bb3-4e2d-ad42-fd9103ebcdd9/32/40940/1
05-02 12:05:57.595 26211-26211/com.syzygy.extreme.sdealscustomer I/System.out: onErrorResponse-CUSTOMER_LOGIN- null
```

Comment: what code used in android?

Comment: @NehaK code updated. Any code is okay. please help me.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR, did u check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135008/unexpected-response-code-500-for-post-method

Comment: please check internet connection is it working fine in mobile

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with your RequestProperty :

**Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8**

You should set that as **application/json**

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
       headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
       return headers;
}
```