# POST Method not using Params

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I dont know why the getParams() is not working in my method?

The System.out.println works fine under getHeaders but not under getParams?

```
    //---------------------------------------POST request with headers---------------------------------------
public void post(String url, final String param1, final String param2, String source) {

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            getReponse(source), createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("loginAlias", "username");
            params.put("loginPassword", "12345");
            System.out.println("Params are: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put(ACCEPT, ACCEPT_JSON); //Accepting JSON
            headers.put(AUTH_ID, AUTH_ID_VALUE);  
            headers.put(PLATFORM, PLATFORM_VALUE); 
            headers.put(CID, ""); 
            headers.put(DEVICE_TYPE_MOBILE, DEVICE_TYPE_MOBILE_VALUE); 
            System.out.println("Headers are: " + headers.toString());
            return headers;
        }
    };
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(request);
}
```

I have followed all the Google Volley documentation and tried a couple options on SO but for some reason, this does not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also faced the same issue, Finally I found that there is some issue with volley - JSONObject request. (after few googling!)

the **getParams()** doesn't invoke because **JsonObjectRequest** extended **JsonRequest** which invoke **getBody()** directly to encoding the constructor second parameter(call requestBody) as contentType, that's why it ignore your **getParam()** method.

try this solution, it resolved my problem.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;    
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;

public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
            Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
            Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

In activity/fragment do use this

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Method.POST, url, params, this.createRequestSuccessListener(), this.createRequestErrorListener());

requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

[Volley JsonObjectRequest Post request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working)

Comment: Ah amazing!!!! time to refactor my code! can remove all my different methods with the different request types ie POST, GET, PUT, DELETE etc! amazing!!

Comment: I think this has fixed my Caching issue that i also had?? nothing was Caching at all now it seems to be? am i right that it should be doing it?

Comment: yeah.., the line HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)); will manage it. :-)