# How to format POST parameters using Volley JSONObjectRequest

Tags: android, json, post, request, android-volley

There seems to be an overwhelming amount of confusion to using Volley to do this. I have seen 20+ questions asking how to do this, but still I don't know why what I am doing is getting an empty response.

```
{"results":[]}
```

Here is the code I use to setup the JSONObjectRequest

```
    String url = "http://bsg.redmatmediabizapp.com/admin/push/getPushNotifications.php";
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("AppVersion", "BSG");
        params.put("userID", "2");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO handle error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    populateNavigationDrawer(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //TODO Handle Error
                    Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
                }
            });

    singleton.addToRequestQueue(request);
```

If I pass the same url and parameter key:value pairs to http://hurl.it I get a longer response, so I know the server is responding correctly.

Comment: I think you have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19945676/1032167

Comment: excellent! I guess I should start searching for answers that are voted up the most.

Comment: Funny thing is I think I based the code for this question off another answer to that question, but didn't work ... :( but YES the answer make as correct to that question worked for me here, maybe mark this as duplicate