# Volley sends null parameters to server

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to send JSON parameter but server is receiving them as nulls values,
i tried to request it from Postman and it works perfect, i don't know what the problem is with volley  i followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working) but it didn't make sense

here is my code

```
String url = "http://10.10.10.166:8080/SystemManagement/api/Profile/Login";
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

    try {
        jsonObject.put("user_id","Test user name");
        jsonObject.put("user_password","test password");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(  Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {



                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println(error.toString());

                }
            });
    //add request to queue
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: The instructions were to extend the `JsonObjectRequest` request class and implement your own `getParams` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same problem, solved by overriding the `getParams()` method

Here is my login request using Volley.

```
private void loginRequeset() {
            showpDialog();

            StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // hide the progress dialog
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            })

            {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> signup_param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    signup_param.put(Constants.USERNAME, _emailText.getText().toString().trim());
                    signup_param.put(Constants.PASSWORD, _passwordText.getText().toString().trim());
                    return signup_param;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            queue.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        }
```

Comment: how did you send json object here ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi `return signup_param`

Comment: No need of _json object_ getParams() return Map<String, String>. You can add your `jsonObject.put("user_id","Test user name");
 jsonObject.put("user_password","test password");`
to
`signup_param.put("user_id","Test user name");
signup_param.put("user_password","test password");`

Comment: you can use `getBody()`  method as mention in this post [Use getBody method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19838007/5955593)