# Volley ClientError Unexpected response code 404

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am getting com.android.volley.ClientError exception in onErrorResponse. Below my code. Initially the code works using volley 'StringRequest'; when I change it to use JsonObjectRequest I got the error. I think the error is related to the request parameters. They are not sent to the service. The test REST service is written in .NET but that won't make any difference.

```
private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/Test.App.REST/api/User/";

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("EmployeeId", "01123");
params.put("Environment", "DAT");

CustomRequest jsonRequest = new CustomRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        ControlUserResponse resp = (ControlUserResponse) gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ControlUserResponse.class);
                        respTxt.setText(resp.firstName + " -- " + resp.lastName);
                    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                        respTxt.setText(e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    respTxt.setText(error.toString());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

I use the helper class CustomRequest from this url
[Volley JsonObjectRequest Post request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820)

I can test that the url below is working fine on my machine from the browser and returning the correct data
http://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/Test.App.REST/api/User/?EmployeeId=01123&Environment=DAT

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Exception stack trace below:

```
04-26 14:48:27.180 9441-9574/test.app.resttest E/Volley: [308] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://XXX.XX.X.XXX/Test.App.REST/api/User
04-26 14:48:27.183 9441-9441/test.app.resttest W/System.err: com.android.volley.ClientError
04-26 14:48:27.183 9441-9441/asc.app.resttest W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:164)
04-26 14:48:27.183 9441-9441/asc.app.resttest W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Comment: please post the error message

Comment: error message posted above

Answer (score 2):

I have changed my code. Now I am getting the correct result from the REST service

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(ENDPOINT).buildUpon();
builder.appendQueryParameter("EmployeeId", "12345555");
builder.appendQueryParameter("Environment", "DEV");

JsonObjectRequest  jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, builder.toString(), null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        ControlUserResponse resp = (ControlUserResponse) gson.fromJson(response.toString(), ControlUserResponse.class);
                        respTxt.setText(resp.firstName + " -- " + resp.lastName);
                    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                        respTxt.setText(e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    respTxt.setText(error.toString());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

Comment: Looks like you just changed the endpoint... Makes sense considering a 404 Not Found error

Comment: By the way, `GsonRequest` is available here. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html