# How to send Post request using Volley in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am sending a volley request like this

```
  btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            //submitForm();
            JsonObjectRequest jsonobjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //errorlabel.setText(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    errorlabel.setText("Invalid username / password");
                }

            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", "asd@asd.com");
                    params.put("password", "asd");



                    return params;
                }
            };
            errorlabel.setText(jsonobjectRequest.toString());
            requestQueue.add(jsonobjectRequest);

        }
    });




}
```

But I get an error message from the server saying invalid email/password.

I have set up the correct params. I tested it out on Postman and it works in there. Here is a screenshot.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you try with StringRequest?

Comment: there is a bug in JSONObject request, you cannot send params: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working ,
You need to try with StringRequest that will work for sure.

Comment: Doing it with string request worked. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: For future reference, you should post the **exact error message** when you ask a question.

Comment: Did you echo and see what email/password the server received?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and i tried with String request, its working

```
 StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
               URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();

                postParam.put("email", "asd@asd.com");
                postParam.put("password", "asd");


                return postParam;
            }

        };

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjRequest);
```