# convert Response into JSON ARRAY or OBJECT in android volley,php,xampp mysql

Tags: java, php, android

I am doing an android project the login API is working properly in postman but for JSON format it is showing Unexpected 'S'. My colleague told me to convert the Response in LoginRequest.java must be changed to either JSONArray or JSONObject

Here are PHP, Android JAVA codes

```
    <?php

include("Connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{

   $email=$_POST["email"];

   $password=$_POST["password"];

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user_master where email='$email' && password='$password'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {   
        echo "Success";
        exit;
    }           
    else
    {   
        echo "INVALID";
        exit;
    }
}


?>
```

LoginRequest.java

```
    package com.talentakeaways.ttpms;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by chand on 15-03-2018.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String url = "http://10.26.16.22:80/ttpms/login.php";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;

    LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("username", username);
        parameters.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Ttpm_Login.java

```
    package com.talentakeaways.ttpms;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import info.androidhive.androidsplashscreentimer.R;


public class Ttpm_Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    //declaration of edit text, button and string values
    EditText tenantname, passWord;
    Button bt_login;
    String userName, password;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ttpm_login);
        setTitle("Login"); //set title of the activity
        initialize();
        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Ttpm_Login.this);
        //onClickListener method for button
        bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //assigning String variables to the text in edit texts
                userName = tenantname.getText().toString();
                password = passWord.getText().toString();
                //Validating the String values
                if (validateUsername(userName) && validatePassword(password)) {

                    //Start ProgressDialog
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Ttpm_Login.this);
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging You In");
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();

                    //Login Request from class LoginRequest
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userName, password, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("Login Response", response);
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                //If Success then start Dashboard Activity
                                if (jsonObject.getBoolean("Success")) {

                                    Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ttpm_Dashboard.class);
                                    startActivity(loginSuccess);
                                    finish();
                                }

                                //else Invalid
                                else {
                                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("INVALID"))
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords Don't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Response from the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Connection Timed Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(loginRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialize() {
        tenantname = findViewById(R.id.tenantname);
        passWord = findViewById(R.id.password);
        bt_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    }

    private boolean validateUsername(String string) {
        //Validating the entered USERNAME
        if (string.equals("")) {
            tenantname.setError("Enter a Username");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() > 50) {
            tenantname.setError("Maximum 50 Characters");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() < 6) {
            tenantname.setError("Minimum 6 Characters");
            return false;
        }
        tenantname.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword(String string) {
        //Validating the entered PASSWORD
        if (string.equals("")) {
            passWord.setError("Enter Your Password");
            return false;
        } else if (string.length() > 32) {
            passWord.setError("Maximum 32 Characters");
            return false;
        }
//        else if (string.length() < 8) {
//            passWord.setError("Minimum 8 Characters");
//            return false;
//        }
//
        passWord.setEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And Here is my logcat when perform login
https://i.stack.imgur.com/94CGd.png

Please Help. Thanks In advance

Comment: share your response

Comment: response in postman or android.

Comment: @ChandraKiran your post key is wrong, see my answer below

Comment: [please refer this link.This will help you to get json response.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820)

Comment: @Navneet I changed it to what you said but still, it is taking the error in the catch block but not going to try block

Comment: use log in tray block and check the error

Comment: @ChandraKiran you don't need a jsonobject here since the response is a single string, check my updated answer

Comment: I changed it to your code @Navneet then I understood that it is never getting the response as "Success" to go to next activity

Answer (score 0):

Your post parameters are wrong, in your backend you are expecting the key `email` but in android you are posting `username`, change username to email in app

```
LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener);
    parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("email", username);
    parameters.put("password", password);
}
```

Since your response is a string, no need of converting it to jsonobject. Change response block like this

```
   LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(userName, password, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("Login Response", response);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            //If Success then start Dashboard Activity
                            if(jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {

                                Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Ttpm_Dashboard.class);
                                startActivity(loginSuccess);
                                finish();
                            }

                            //else Invalid
                            else {
                                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("INVALID"))
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Passwords Don't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                            Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Response from the Server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Connection Timed Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            Toast.makeText(Ttpm_Login.this, "Bad Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(loginRequest);
```

Comment: I changed it to your code @Navneet then I understood that it is never getting the response as "Success" to go to next activity shall I share my new code@Navneet

Comment: have you checked `logcat` , is `response` null ?

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: in your logcat option at bottom, you have a search option, serach for `Login Response`

Comment: here success is your key and response is a jsonobject but in your php its a string response, i will update the code now

Comment: @ChandraKiran in your existing code which you have, just  change the spelling of success to smaller case `jsonObject.getBoolean("success")`

Comment: @ChandraKiran you will require a `jsonObject` itself,  i have updated my answer as well

Comment: 03-21 13:01:03.313 18329-18329/com.talentakeaways.ttpms W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

For Example
If you view the JSON structure, it will be something like this:

```
{
```

"results" : [
      {
   "user_login" : "xyz",
         "user_login_password" : 123456
      } ]
}

First, convert the JSON object into JSONArray object like this:

```
    JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get(“results”); 
 for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++)
{
  JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);
  System.out.println(“Elements under results array”);
  System.out.println(“\nuser_login: ” +jsonobj_1.get(“user_login”));
  System.out.println(“user_login_password: ” +jsonobj_1.get(“user_login_password”));
}
```

and send the parameter to server:

```
 protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

          /** Pass the parameters to according to the API.*/
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user_login", edt_email.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("user_login_password", edt_password.getText().toString().trim());
            return params;
        }
    };
    /** Adding request to request queue*/
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, cancel_login_api);
}
```