# Unable to send Json object to server in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I know this question is asked already but still it didn't work for me. I am unable to send Json object to server. Iam not getting any response from server. What mistake I have done here. If I made a silly mistake please don't mark as duplicate or block my account. I am absolutely new to programming. I have attached the solution given by Satck overflow.[seethis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837820/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-not-working)

```
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
                response.add("Description", a1 );/*a1 is Json array of 
         multiple values*/
                response.add("Amount", a2 );/*a2 is Json array of 
         multiple values*/
                System.out.println("Json:"+response);/*Both the list is saved inside this Json object*/

                Map<String,String> hm = new HashMap();
                hm.put("Values",String.valueOf(response));/*Trying to pass the json object to server respose is the Json object*/

                 CustomRequest req = new 
      CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,ip,hm,
      this.createRequestSuccessListener(),       
      this.createRequestErrorListener()); 

                Mysingleton.getInstance(this).addTorequestque(req);/*This 
        is a singleton class*/
   public Response.Listener<JSONObject> createRequestSuccessListener(){
    return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            AlertDialog.Builder al = new AlertDialog.Builder(Database.this)
                    .setTitle("Message")
                    .setMessage("Sent")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",null);
            AlertDialog al1 = al.create();
            al.show();
        }
    };
}

public Response.ErrorListener createRequestErrorListener(){
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            AlertDialog.Builder al = new AlertDialog.Builder(Database.this)
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage("Something went wrong")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",null);
            AlertDialog al1 = al.create();
            al.show();
        }
    };
}

 [CustomRequet][1]

My php source code is here
 if(!empty($_POST['Values']){
      $all_arraylist = json_decode(Values,true);
       $ result = print_r($all_arraylist,true);
       echo $result;
    }
     else{
    echo "Empty";
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your logs? Are you you using [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) or some other class? Also, if you're referring to an existing solution that you've tried, it's generally a good practice to link it in your post.

Comment: Share errors logs.

Comment: I don't get any response here

Comment: can you reach server in android web-browser outside of you app?

Comment: No I if I check the server it is printing as "Empty"

Comment: Guys can anyone please help me to figure out what is the problem??