# Pass params Using GET method using volley library

Tags: android, android-volley, getmethod

How can we pass params from editText to `url` using `request.GET` method.
Actually I am trying to pass an email address as parameter to a `api` which should b attached to `api-url` .

I came to know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484647/volley-does-not-call-getparams-for-my-custom-request) that getParams() is not called on the GET method, so it seems you'll have to add it to the URL before you send the request.
suggest me  any solution to achieve the task ..

when i pass REG_URL="http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/registeruser?email=ameer@novatoresols.com";
it return success=true response as expected because is registered user
but if i set REG_URL="http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/registeruser and pass the params (get value from edittext and use params.put in getparams() method ).response is always success=false i.e params is not attached to url
here is my code.

```
    package com.example.mts3.hammadnewsapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_verf;
    EditText et_Email;
    String u_emails,stat;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    Context context;
//    public static String firstname, lastname, useremail, userphone, userpass;


//    String REG_URL="http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/registeruser?email=ameer@novatoresols.com";
    String REG_URL="http://ec2-54-147-238-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com/hmc/api/registeruser";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btn_verf=findViewById(R.id.btn_reg_send_vf_code);
        et_Email=findViewById(R.id.et_reg_email);
        alertDialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
//        u_emails=et_Email.getText().toString().trim();


        btn_verf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callApi();
            }
        });
    }

    private void callApi() {
//        Log.e(TAG, "onClick: ");
        /*if (!utility.isInternetConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }*/
//        dialog = utility.showProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Please wait");
        final String email = et_Email.getText().toString().trim();

//        Log.e(TAG, "onClick: email = " + email );

//        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
/*
        HashMap<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
        params.put("email",email);*/
        /*try {
//            params.getString("email");
            params.put("email",email);
            Log.e(TAG, "getParams: param = " + "try of put prams");
        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getParams: param = " + "catch of put prams");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);



        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, REG_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "REsponse: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
//                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("email",email);
                return params;

            }
        };        queue.add(stringRequest);


    }
}
```

Comment: What are challenges you faced after passing the parameters in the url??

Comment: Can you post your code where you are facing problem

Comment: You have posted a question and the solution. Whats the problem?

Comment: did you just try to pass a body in GET request ??

Comment: @Xenolion sir I have edited my post .kindly see if my problem is understandable

Comment: @Puneet sir I have edited my post .kindly see if my problem is understandable

Comment: @HarshSinghal sir I have edited my post .kindly see if my problem is understandable

Comment: getParams is only called for POST requests. GET requests don't have a body and hence, getParams is never called. For a simple request like yours just add the parameters to your URL and use that constructed URL to make that request to your server (REG_URL + "?email=" + email).

Comment: thanks @Puneet it worked .

Comment: I was offline but I think you get a very nice answer! @ZiafatRaheemKhokhar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Puneet worked for me which is as :

`getParams` is only called for `POST` requests. `GET` requests don't have a body and hence, `getParams` is never called. For a simple request like yours just add the parameters to your `URL` and use that constructed `URL` to make that request to your server `(REG_URL + "?email=" + email)`.

Comment: I have just formatted your answer! and it is good! +1. **Happy Coding!**.

Comment: Awesome, you opened my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the parameters, you need to create a class for the key-value pairs.

1) Create a class `KeyValuePair` with two fields `key` and `value` with appropriate constructor and getter-setter methods.

2) Now, for *each* parameter, you need to create *an object* of this class, i.e., for a key **username** with value **user@gmail.com**, the object would be `new KeyValuePair("username", "user@gmail.com")`.

3) Now, you need to create a `List` to store these parameters and pass this list to the below method with your base url,

```
 public static String generateUrl(String baseUrl, List<KeyValuePair> params) {
    if (params.size() > 0) {
        for (KeyValuePair parameter: params) {
            if (parameter.getKey().trim().length() > 0)
                baseUrl += "&" + parameter.getKey() + "=" + parameter.getValue();
        }
    }
    return baseUrl;
}
```

4) Pass this *baseUrl* to your `Request`.

Comment: With this method am only able to pass first parameter in my List,second one is undefined